# Golang debug in VSCode on macOS issues

Tags: go, debugging, visual-studio-code

I need to debug a golang application in vscode on macos, but had been unsuccessful to do so.
the error get is:

```
API server listening at: 127.0.0.1:49512
could not launch process: not an executable file
Process exiting with code: 1
```

and this is my GO ENV

```
go version go1.16.6 darwin/amd64

Delve Debugger
Version: 1.7.0
Build: $Id: e353a65161e6ed74952b96bbb62ebfc56090832b $

GO111MODULE=""
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/Users/francois/Library/Caches/go-build"
GOENV="/Users/francois/Library/Application Support/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOINSECURE=""
GOMODCACHE="/Users/francois/go/pkg/mod"
GONOPROXY="gitlab.com/baltussen"
GONOSUMDB="gitlab.com/baltussen"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/Users/francois/go"
GOPRIVATE="gitlab.com/baltussen"
GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"
GOROOT="/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.16.6/libexec"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.16.6/libexec/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
GOVCS=""
GOVERSION="go1.16.6"
GCCGO="gccgo"
AR="ar"
CC="clang"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="0"
GOMOD="/Users/francois/DiVision/baltussen/pat-be/go.mod"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/var/folders/n8/xbwvwsg55_s5clpxq778nrg80000gn/T/go-build3775586407=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
```

I have already uninstalled go and installed it again.
I also removed the go extensions from vs-code and re-added it again.
I also tried various launch.json version, but had no luck so far.
Here is my launch.json file:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "GoLang",
      "type": "go",
      "request": "launch",
      "mode": "auto",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "env": {
        "PATH": "/usr/local/go/bin:${fileDirname}"
      },
      "args": []
    }
  ]
}
```

Any ideas or suggestions would be welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the path to the main.go file, if that file does not directly reside in your workspace directory.

I have a configuration that looks like the following:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch file",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "debug",
            "program": "${file}",
            "env": {         
            },
            "args": [     
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "auto",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/cmd/service/main.go",
            "env": {            
            },
            "args": [
            ]           
        }
    ]
}
```

It consists of 2 parts.

1. Launch currently open file
2. Launch main.go file under specified path using `"program": "${workspaceFolder}/cmd/service/main.go"`

You could exchange the `/cmd/service/main.go` path to the path that matches your project structure.

When having multiple configs, you can switch between them in the **Run and Debug** tab.

[image: screenshot of run an debug]

Answer (score 0):

Did you run `$ dlv debug` in golang-project folder?

Go debugger must works without VSCode. Try fix some parameters for your `ENV`:

```sh
GOOS="darwin"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

[image]

- [x] `$ dlv debug`